# jQuery - how to show external web page if > 2 checkbox selected?

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

What I'm trying to do is when user click the 2 checkboxes it will pop up new window web page. I got the solution for 1 checkbox but i have hard time figuring out on how to do in both. I tried or || or and && but i didnt work.

Here my code:

```
<?php
 // when user clicked no checkbox

if(isset($_POST['bus']) &&
   $_POST['bus'] == 'bar' &&  $_POST['bus'] != 'carryout')
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> window.open("http://yahoo.com", target="_self"); 
</script>'; 
}

// when user clicked yes checkbox

if(isset($_POST['bus']) && 
   $_POST['bus'] == 'bar' &&  $_POST['bus'] != 'carryout')
{
      echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
window.open("http://google.com", target="_self"); 
</script>'; 
}

else{

/// when user clicked both checkboxes
if(isset($_POST['bus']) && $_POST['bus'] == 'bar' &&
   $_POST['bus'] == 'carryout')
{

  echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
window.open("http://getvms.com", target="_self"); 
</script>'; 
}}
?>

form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">

 Type of restaurant are you?<br>
    <br>
    BAR
    input type="checkbox" name="bus" id="1" value="bar" ?php if(isset($_POST['bus'])) ?>/><br>

 CARRYOUT input type="checkbox" name="bus" id="2"value="carryout" ?php if(isset($_POST['bus']))?>/>

input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: fix you formatting first please

Comment: Why are you using two `checkbox` elements for a `Yes/No` question? Seems like you'd be better off using a single `checkbox`, or two `radio` buttons.

Comment: The type of question you're asking your user requires **radio buttons instead of checkboxes**.

Comment: You need to have checkboxes with different names, so they come through as separate $_POST properties.  Obviously, $_POST['formWheelchair'] cannot be both Yes and No at the same time.

Comment: @mellamokb: If they were radio buttons they'd be fine with the same name.

Comment: yes/no is just a sample but that could change to a service. let assume yes is bar and no is carryout. when user click BAR then a pop up page bar show and if user click Carryout then a pop up page Carry out show and then if user click both then we have other page for Carryout and bar. We use this concept to give the right credit card terminal base on answer..Hope this help.

Comment: You seem to have some weird PHP logic going on in your actual `<form>` as well... At first glance, it appears that it doesn't show the `No` option or the `Submit` button unless the form has already been submitted.

Comment: @dinah: Are you doing anything with the submitted data in PHP other than using it for the popup windows?

Comment: yes.when the page loaded after they answer the question, whatever data they inputted in the external page will be save to our database.

Comment: @dinah: You made the code unreadable again. Select all the code block and click the curly braces icon: `{}`, or press `Ctrl+K`. Check what it looks like in the preview right under the textarea before posting.

Comment: @dinah: It's better if you explain what you are trying to achieve. It is not clear if you are trying to get the effect *after* submitting the form, or *as soon as* a checkbox is checked.

Comment: i need when user click bar it will go to bar external page and if user click carryout it will go to carryout external page and then if user click both both it will go to a carryoutbar external page. This code is for survey. page load base on their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = false;

if(isset($_POST['bar']) && isset($_POST['carryout'])) $url = 'http://carryoutbar.com';
elseif(isset($_POST['carryout'])) $url = 'http://carryout.com';
elseif(isset($_POST['bar'])) $url = 'http://bar.com'; // nice place, pay foo a visit!

if($url) echo '
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      window.open("' . $url . '", target="_self"); 
    </script>';
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

Please select:<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="1" /> BAR<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="carryout" value="1" /> Carryout<br/>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: OMG, u got it!...thank you Majid...Thanks everyone! I used If then Elseif and else if as Majid advice..thanks for all the input! GOD BLESS U ALL!

Comment: In your form action, instead of `$PHP_SELF`, you should use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Answer (score 2):

### Track your checked state

If you need to count checkboxes then introduce an array of values. SUppose your checkboxes are named as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" data="singleURL1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" data="singleURL2" />
```

then you could be doing it this way:

```
$(function(){

    var checked = {
        cb1: false,
        cb2: false,
        both: function(){
            return this.cb1 && this.cb2;
        },
        allUrl: "some combined URL"
    };

    $(":input:checkbox").click(function(){
        checked[this.name] = this.checked;
        if (checked.both() === true)
        {
            var url = checked.allUrl;
            // open combined URL
        }
        else
        {
            var url = $(this).attr("data");
            // open single checkbox URL
        }
    });

});
```

I've put all the code inside a DOM ready anonymous function enclosure that can be used as is.

Comment: I dont need count.. i need when user click both it will go to a external page. This code is need for survey. page load base on their answer.

Comment: @dinah: I've now changed my code and put it in a DOM ready function closure. You can easily use it as is if it provides the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can do `$('input:checkbox').click(function(){...})`

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Looks like you were using the example on http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html To get the multiple values scroll down to the example where they use checkbox groups, ie. change your name from `formWheelchair` to `formWheelchair[]` so it will return as an array in PHP

Comment: @yes123  i didnt get what you mean?